# Software only USB implementation for ARM-M0/M0+?

Tags: usb, usb-device, software, firmware

Since I'm worried about the future of AVR, I've been looking into software USB for ARM cortex-M0/M0+ that is similar to V-USB.  All I've found is a port of LUFA, which is for MCUs with internal USB hardware.

Now I know there are Cortex-M0/M0+ controllers that do have USB hardware, although I'm looking at using the smallest lowest pin-count I possibly can which usually don't have USB hardware.  I know some of these tiny controllers will have USB hardware but they are typically in a WLCSP package which have small spacing between the pads which I cannot work with.  This is why I'm looking for a software implementation.

Is there a software only implementation of USB for ARM-M0/M0+?

**note:** by software, I mean firmware but it seems code-only implementations of hardware peripherals are usually referred to by software.

**note 2:** Please don't suggest any specific products.  The question isn't about an inability to find small controllers with USB, its about the lack of a software implementation of USB for ARM much like V-USB.

Comment: I once saw some example firmware to bit-bang a USB low-speed peripheral (HID keyboard I think) ... I doubt you'll get much better than that.

Comment: USB low speed is fine.  The controllers don't have the capabilities to fill the bandwidth anyway

Comment: I could saturate a 12 MBit/s USB FS connection with a Cortex M3 at about 48 MHz, just by reading from SD card.

Comment: @TurboJ Sorry, I should've said my code doesn't have the capability, as well as the controllers I have right now.  ARM controllers may be able to.  Still looking for a stack though.  seems like the one brhans was talking about is for the Gecko controllers only.  Could port it but that would take time I don't have.

Comment: I wouldn't get too worried about the future of AVR just yet. Immediately obsoleting their acquisitions parts is not their MO.

Comment: If pin pitch is a problem, maybe just take a MCU board on a DIL carrier board or something similar. Ive used a FRDM-KL25Z board to build ontop of before. Also, dont rule out M3/M4 unless cost is super-critical.

Comment: STM32F042Fx would be a good fit, I think. TSSOP20 can be soldered by hand, it is very small, Cortex-M0 and crystal-less USB.

Comment: Please stop commenting with links recommending specific products.  This question isn't about that and it is off topic for this stack exchange

Comment: I find it ironic that you are worried about AVR (likely due to the Microchip buyout), and want a software-USB implementation for a low-pincount device. If you look at Microchip's devices, you will find that _they_ have down to 14-pin PICs with integrated hardware USB, in a reasonable size for hand-soldering.

Comment: @pipe they aren't ARM. Read the question

Comment: @Funkyguy I did read your question. All of it, in fact. Not just the title. You have a problem which you're trying to solve in a way that's not the most rational. Expect comments and answers trying to solve the root issue.

Comment: @dim  The question isn't about not finding small controllers with USB hardware, its about the lack of a software stack for ARM.  You can do exactly this with AVR using V-USB.  There is no reason, apart from it hasn't been written yet, that you couldn't do this with ARM.

Comment: @Funkyguy Please see the guidelines for writing good questions http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Questions that are unanswerable will be nixed (by multiple people). This is not a discussion website, it has a Q&A format.

Comment: You are looking for something like [LemcUSB](https://github.com/lemcu/LemcUSB).  GNU GPL 3.0 is ok?  I can expect next question about porting Micronucleus to ARM :)

Comment: there's quite a few libraries that have popped up: http://www.embedds.com/bit-banging-usb-on-msp430/ https://hackaday.com/2014/03/22/bitbanging-usb-on-low-power-arms/

Answer (score 6):

Here's a new M0+ implementation comparable to V-USB
https://github.com/xobs/grainuum

Interesting 33c3 video explaining as well: https://youtu.be/GFY_A3jcI28

Still pretty fresh and prob not as stable as V-USB but sounds promising.  Curious how vital the 2 stage pipeline of the M0+ really is as would be nice to implement this on M0.

Doesn't sound like he's so tight that he can't afford one more cycle with the 3 stage pipeline.  I think the biggest issue will be M0's lack of single cycle I/O ports which is an optional feature of the M0+.  But he makes it sound like the pipeline is the real benefit of M0+.

Answer (score -2):

It is not really too feasible. Because today many microcontrollers are fabricated for 2.5V down to 1.8V operating ranges. The software implementation through simple I/O toggling will not handle the high speed differential operation without a dedicated PHY on silicon (with special tranceivers). V-USB was working on AVR because it used on microcontrollers operating on 5V. There are no many of them on modern designs.

Comment: V-USB required the MCU to be running at 3.3V, or a crude zener diode based level shifter to be used if it was running at 5V.

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I have confirmed Cortex M0 operating at 3.3V. So for that models it still totally feasible. Someone can port V-USB to ARM.